# В docker не могу добавить репозиторий ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gcc, apt-get, pgp

Всем привет.

Как обычно, пишу после примерно полудня разных экспериментов, ни один из кторых не привел к результату.

Хочу поэкспериментировать с новой (10.1) версией gcc.

Запускаю, естественно, в контейнере.

Чтобы поставить последнюю версию компилятора, следую инструкции
https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91

На шаге

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

получаю сообщение о том, что "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.", а потом целый букет питоновских ошибок:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
 Toolchain test builds; see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpj2fw7gd9/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpj2fw7gd9/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 1E9377A2BA9EF27F: public key "Launchpad Toolchain builds" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 491, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 449, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 447, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
```

Перепробовал - просто всё, что ищется по ключевым словам.

1. пробовал удалять (--remove) и опять добаволять репозиторий
2. сделал всё по инструкции по работе с gnupg: https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html
3. Перекинул в контейнер свои собственный ключи из директории .ssh
4. Проверил питоновскую ошибку:

   ```
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
   ```

Такой файл в системе есть, полный путь к нему -

```
    /home/coder/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

И на этом, честно говоря, у меня идеи кончились. я пробовал сравнивать директории в "работающей" и "не работающей" системе, но ничего существенного не заметил.

Не подскажете ли Вы, что еще можно сделать чтобы добавить этот несчастный репозиторий внутри докер - контейнера?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

запустил команду:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:20.04 bash -c 'apt-get update && \
 apt-get -y install gnupg && \
 apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 1E9377A2BA9EF27F && \
 echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal main" > \
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test.list && \
 apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc-10 && gcc-10 --version'
```

закончилось всё выводом сообщения от gcc-10:

```
gcc-10 (Ubuntu 10-20200416-0ubuntu1) 10.0.1 20200416 (experimental) [master revision 3c3f12e2a76:dcee354ce56:44b326839d864fc10c459916abcc97f35a9ac3de]
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

если образ от другой версии дистрибутива будете использовать, то подправьте [имя выпуска](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames) (`20.04` — это `focal`)

p.s. а ещё там символическая ссылка не создаётся, чтоб можно было вызывать просто как `gcc`. создайте при необходимости:

```
$ ln -s gcc-10 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Шикарно! Большое спасибо за подсказку! Еще не сделал, но вижу в команде, как именно прописывается этот репозиторий, это то, чего мне не хватало!